# Browser partial autocomplete

Tags: iphone, web-browser, auto-complete

I come from the Android world and I have a new iPhone. I am trying to find how to replicate a feature that I am used to, about the browser search autocomplete.

Say I want to search Google for the following phrase: "wikipedia star wars a new hope". Of course in this particular case I could use a Wikipedia search provider, but that is not the point.

In the Android browser, I can start typing "wi" and the browser will search and suggest "wikipedia". I can then click on a button and complete "wikipedia" and **keep writing**. At this point, maybe I will write "sta" and the browser will suggest "wikipedia star wars". Again, I click and have this phrase in the search bar, and keep writing. I then add "a n" and probably the browser will suggest the complete phrase "wikipedia star wars a new hope" that I can click to actually search.

This is an enormous time saver whenever searching for longish phrases. In Safari, I get the autocomplete, but if, say, after writing "wi" I click on the suggestion "wikipedia", it is searched immediately, which makes impossible to keep writing.

Is there a way to activate this feature in Safari? Does any other browser provide it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out Firefox does not implement this, while Chrome does.